# I'm getting an syntax error in a stored procedure in sql with an underscore

Tags: mysql, sql

```
String insertStoredProcedure = "BEGIN " + 
                                    "SELECT COUNT(p.PassengerID) " +
                                    "INTO numpeople " + 
                                    "FROM tripcodes as tc " + 
                                    "INNER JOIN trip_directory as td on tc.tripType = td.tripType " + 
                                    "INNER JOIN trip t on td.tripnum = t.tripnum " + 
                                    "INNER JOIN locations as loc on t.departureloccode = loc.locationcode " + 
                                    "INNER JOIN trip_people as tp on t.date = tp.date AND t.tripnum=tp.tripnum " + 
                                    "INNER JOIN passenger as p on tp.passengerid = p.passengerid " + 
                                    "WHERE tc.typename = transportation; " + 
                                    "END ";
```

whenever I try to run the program. I keep getting

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT COUNT(p.PassengerID) INTO numpeople FROM tripcodes as tc
>   INNER JOIN trip_' at line 1"

I'm not quite sure how to fix this if anyone could help me I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Comment: That is no stored procedure. Remove the `begin` and `end`

Comment: If your question relates to SQL, strip out all the non SQL cruft like the string concatenation that's an artifact of how you're executing it.

Comment: You're showing how you attempted to define the SQL, but you don't show how you're trying to run it.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, `BEGIN`/`END` are used for programming blocks.  Programming blocks do not simply exist.  They must be part of some stored program.  The ones that come to mind are:

- Stored procedures
- User defined functions
- Procedures

If you want a stored procedure (as your title suggests), then you need `CREATE PROCEDURE . . .` *before* the `BEGIN`.

Your code does not requires a stored procedure.  I would suggest removing the `BEGIN`, the `END`, and the `INTO`.  Just execute the query and read the result set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which programming language you are using, so i give you an answer how it must be done mysql.
The variable **numpeople**  has to be declared somewhere.

In a storede procdure as out variable, like shown in below code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_testprocedure`(OUT numpeople int)
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(p.PassengerID) 
   INTO numpeople 
   FROM tripcodes as tc 
   INNER JOIN trip_directory as td on tc.tripType = td.tripType 
   INNER JOIN trip t on td.tripnum = t.tripnum 
   INNER JOIN locations as loc on t.departureloccode = loc.locationcode 
   INNER JOIN trip_people as tp on t.date = tp.date AND t.tripnum=tp.tripnum 
   INNER JOIN passenger as p on tp.passengerid = p.passengerid 
   WHERE tc.typename = transportation;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You have to see, if you can replicate this in your programming language